# What email list-send services allow suppression based on reply content?

Tags: email, sendgrid, spam-prevention, amazon-ses, mailgun

I'm looking at a variety of mailing services, Mailgun, Amazon SES, SendGrid. Does any one of those services have a way to automatically suppress based on the content of a reply email?

Usually it is customary to use an unsubscribe button, but occasionally a user will reply instead - is there any good documentation or service out there which will parse the title and body of the email for the word unsubscribe - and then automatically blacklist that email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a widely supported use-case anymore, and I don't know of any services that handle that.

With SendGrid, it'd be pretty straightforward to add this functionality, between the [Parse Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) & the [API Unsubscribes.add call](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/unsubscribes.html#-add).